# Who is Bhadra's mother?

Tags: baahubali-the-beginning

In ***Baahubali: The Beginning***, Shiva beheads Bhadra (Adivi Sesh), Bhalla Deva's son. Kattappa drops his weapon, realizing that Shiva is Mahendra Baahubali, the son of late king Amarendra Baahubali.

So the question is, who is Bhadra's mother?

Comment: I think that'd be the new question after *why did Katappa kill Baahubali*. ;-)

Comment: And the answer is not given in its 2nd part Baahubali: The Conclusion either.

Comment: @AJ: And to answer this there might be a **Bahubali Returns** ☺☻.

Answer (score 10):

There were many rumours and gossips that the character of Bhallala Deva's wife will be played by actresses like [Shriya Saran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shriya_Saran) etc ., But the role is not showed in both the movies. Her character is neither shown in *Baahubali The Beginning* nor in  *Baahubali The conclusion*. Not even a portrait.

Same question is asked by an anchor in an [interview](https://youtu.be/xy6bES_T1XY?t=970) of the team of Baahubali during the promotions.

> **Anchor**: Rana(Actor who played the role of Bhallala Deva)! The character of Bhallala Deva's wife is never revealed in the first part in the movie. There were many gossips on who is playing the role. Is wife character of Bhallala Deva revealed in the movie?
>
> **Prabhas**: (humorously)  Rajamouli is not showing any such character. He is afraid that people will curse him for marrying an innocent girl to cunning Bhallala Deva.
>
> Laughs
>
> **Anchor**: Not even a portrait of hers is shown?
>
> **Rana**: **Not even a picture is shown. This story is not about Bhallala Deva's marriage and his love story. His only goal is to reach the throne of *Mahishmati*.**
>
> **Prabhas**: **The background of the characters is not revealed in the movie. That is why we said. *Baahubali* isn't just a movie. It is a world. **Movie is just a branch of Baahubali franchise**. There might be many other branches too.

In the [earlier part](https://youtu.be/xy6bES_T1XY?t=784) of the same interview, Rana and Prabhas said:

> **Prabhas**: Comic books, animation series has been released already. There might be many extensions to this movie. **Movies or shows based on characters might also release**. Anything is possible.
>
> **Rana**: Comic books and books are also released. This is a new approach in Telugu film Industry. But if we observe world wide, This is not new. They don't limit themselves to a movie. Movie is not a tree. It is a branch. And there are many branches let them be comics, video games etc., Many had called us and said the books were better than the movie.(Sivagami role).

We can conclude from their words that *Baahubali The conclusion* is not the end of the franchise. There might be revealment of the characters. Only thing we don't know is when.

If you are wondering what these comics and animation Prabhas and Rana are talking about. Have a look at list below.

- [Rise of Sivagami: Book 1 of Baahubali - Before the Beginning](http://www.amazon.in/Rise-Sivagami-Baahubali-Before-Beginning/dp/9386224445)  - Novel. This is first part of trilogy. Kattappa character is also mentioned in this trilogy.
- [Bāhubali: Battle of the Bold](http://www.amazon.in/dp/9386224658/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_2?pf_rd_p=733112647&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=9386224445&pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_r=08KDA96GM68AEXCV0ZG5) - Comic book.
- [Baahubali: The Lost Legends](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5523460/) - Animated series.

---

But [this](http://allindiaroundup.com/entertainment/bahubali-2-bhallaladeva-wife/) article quotes director S.S Rajamouli's words:

> As surprising and hugely weird it might sound – the evil king Bhallaladeva has probably married no one. Bhallaladeva, who would be turned down by Devasena as the latter chooses Amarendra Baahubali as her life partner over the former, would choose to remain unmarried as Bhalla’s initial love towards Devasena refuses to die down. Hence he remains a bachelor for life.

When asked about Bhadra's birth, He explained:

> "Bhalla’s son, Bhadra, would not be Bhalla’s biological son but instead an adopted son.

However, the article doesn't quote any video source.

Answer (score 0):

The mother of Bhadra / wife of Bhalla Dev had no importance for the plot. So, she was never mentioned in movie. 
We don't have anyway to know what is her name. We only know she is wife of Bhalla Dev.

Answer (score -1):

The movie revolves around the tussle between two cousins Baahubali and Bhallala Deva. In *Bahubali The conclusion*, major effort is taken to show the importance of Devasena, and as it is aptly named Bahubali the conclusion. This second part unravels the mystery of the first part #WKKB (Why Kattapa killed Bahubali) and the flashback scenes of Mahendra Bahubali. If the wife of Bhallaladeva has been shown in the first part, then it is fair to raise a question. Adding a new character will only make the story more complicated.